# cant accept value from dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code

```
<html> 
<title></title>
<head></head>
<body>

<div>
<form method="post" action="file_display1.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <label><h4>forward to</h4></label>
        </td>

        <td>
            <select name="section" id="section" class="select"  onsubmit="validate();" required=" " autofocus/>    
            <option selected="selected" value="">---------- Select ----------</option>
            <option value="KSCCF LTD">KSCCF LTD </option>
            <option value="ADMINISTRATION SECTION">ADMINISTRATION SECTION </option>
            <option value="PURCHASE">PURCHASE SECTION</option>
            <option value="BEVARAGES">BEVARAGES SECTION</option>
            <option value="IT">IT SECTION</option>
            <option value="LEGAL">LEGAL SECTION</option>
            <option value="ACCOUNTS">ACCOUNTS SECTION</option>
            <option value="AGREEMENT">AGREEMENT SECTION</option>
            <option value="MEDICAL">MEDICAL SECTION</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","ConcentricLions@336");

mysql_select_db("demo");


if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))

{

 $to_sectionid=$_POST['section'];

 echo $to_sectionid;

 }

 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

in this the variable $to_sectionid not accepting value of drop down to the variable.

please help

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: I don't see any closing `</form>` or any submit button?

Comment: Also, you're trying to close the select in the opening tag. `<select ... />`. It should be `<select ...>` (without the slash) since `select` isn't a self closing tag and you have `</select>` after the options.

Comment: why you are submitting your form to `action=file_display1.php` ? you have submit code on same page ?

Comment: @Swati I'm guessing that file_display1.php is the name of that page.

Answer (score 0):

i assume in your original code you have a submit button and its value is formSubmit. Your issue probably is you redirect your page to filedisplay.php which is another page and your if ... echo commands do not exist in that page. try action="" (means redirecting to same page) or put your php commands in filedisplay.php

Comment: when i add a submit button its working.thanku for your support